# Copy of "Format Document" function in Visual Studio?

Tags: format, indentation

I am looking for an app that can do what the "Format Document" function does in Visual Studio. Something really stupid (maybe even an add-on to a normal text editor) that will basically turn this:

```
<div><table><tr><td><?php echo 'earth'; ?></td></tr></table></div>
```

into this:

```
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <?php echo 'earth'; ?>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use NotePad++ with [Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) plugin

see [here](http://www.bryancook.net/2008/04/visual-studio-format-whole-document-for.html) for more informations.